# Multiple get methods in same class in Django views

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have multiple get methods in the same class. How do I create the urls?

Views.py

```
class DashboardData(viewsets.ViewSet):
      @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
      def get_total(self, request):
            Total = File.objects.all().count()
            return Response(Total, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

      def get_done(self, request):
            Done = File.objects.filter(entry=True).count()
            return Response(Done, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

      def get_not_done(self, request):
            NotDone = File.objects.filter(entry=False).count()
            return Response(NotDone, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            
      def get_pending(self, request):
            Pending = File.objects.filter(entry=False).count()
            return Response(Pending, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

For example:
http://baser_url/dashboard/total_count should call the get_total() method
http://baser_url/dashboard/done_count should call the done_count() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to route view functions more explicitly, then other way of doing so is:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/total_count/', DashboardData.as_view({'get': 'get_total'})),
    ...,
    path('dashboard/done_count/', DashboardData.as_view({'get': 'done_count'})),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register the methods as custom actions and set the **url_path** parameter.

Example:

```
class DashboardData(viewsets.ViewSet):
    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_path='total_count')
    def get_total(self, request):
        Total = File.objects.all().count()
        return Response(Total, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False, url_path='done_count')
    def get_done(self, request):
        Done = File.objects.filter(entry=True).count()
        return Response(Done, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    
    ...
```

urls.py

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('dashboard', views.DashboardData, basename='dashboarddata')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@action` decorator, but with `detail=False` to add the url to the "root" of the viewset.

```
# views.py
class DashboardViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    
    @action(detail=False, url_path="download")
    def get_download(self, request):
        pass

# urls.py in your app
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register("dashboard", DashboardViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

From your example it seems like you might be just fine making one single [APIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#class-based-views) for each function, and then adding them manually with path

```
class DashPendingView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        return Response(pending_things)

url_patterns = [
    path("dashboard/pending/", DashPendingView.as_view(), "dash-pending")
]
```