# How to list all objs and retrieve single obj using django drf generic views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create a single class based view for retrieving, listing, and creating all of my orders. I have gotten create and retrieve to work but listing is giving some problems. I am using DRF generic views to extend my view and have added the generics.ListApiView to my class. Once I added this however my retrieve route started acting unusual. It is returning to me a list of all the orders when I just want a specific one.

I tried to just add the generics.ListApiView to my class and override the list and get_queryset functions but that just started to affect my retrieve view.

```
class Order(generics.ListAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = addOrderSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        return Order.objects.filter(user=user)

    def get_object(self):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        obj = Order.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return obj

    def get_item_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return addItemSerializer(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_shipping_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return addShippingSerializer(*args, **kwargs)


    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        data = request.data
        orderItems = data.get('orderItems')
        print(data)
        if not bool(orderItems):
            return Response('No Order Items', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            # TODO - Create Order
            orderSerializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
            orderSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            order = orderSerializer.save(user=user)
            
            # TODO - Create Shipping Address
            shippingSerializer = self.get_shipping_serializer(data=data)  
            shippingSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            shippingSerializer.save(order=order)

            # TODO - Create Order Items and Set Order <> OrderItem Relationship
            for item in orderItems:
                product = Product.objects.get(pk=item['product'])
                itemSerializer = self.get_item_serializer(data=item)
                itemSerializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                item = itemSerializer.save(order=order, product=product)
    #         # TODO - Update Product CountInStock
                product.countInStock -= item.qty
                product.save()
            
        return Response(data=orderSerializer.data)


    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        s = self.get_serializer(instance=instance)
        return Response(data=s.data)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        s = self.get_serializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(s.data)
```

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from .. import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Order.as_view()),
    path('add/', views.Order.as_view()),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.Order.as_view({'get':'retrieve'})),
]
```

So in conclusion the list functionality of my view is working now but it has messed up my retrieve functionality. So that the retrieve function is only returning a list even tho I am adding the pk in my url.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your urls.py as well for better clarity ?

Currently based on your question, the issue I see is mentioned below:

1. You are calling class "Order" for retrieve method with some url pattern eg path/int:pk -- Which is a GET request
2. You are also calling same class "Order" for list method with some url pattern eg path/ -- Which is a Get request

The issue is that both Retrieve and List Generic api has a GET method: snippet added :
[image]

Conclusion:
**This is an example of Method Resolution Order in python inheritance.**
Therefore, even though you are trying to invoke a GET method for retrieve it is envoking the GET method of LIST api because in your class definition
class Order(generics.ListAPIView, generics.CreateAPIView, generics.RetrieveAPIView) you have inherited ListAPIView first.

Solution :

1. You should separate out the classes eg: ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView

Alternatively :
You can also follow below stackoverflow answer to route GET request to specific method in same class :

[Multiple get methods in same class in Django views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300610/multiple-get-methods-in-same-class-in-django-views)

[image]

[EDIT]

The above suggested stackoverflow answer seems to be incorrect.

For multiple GET or POST request within same class, you can use Django Viewset and routers.

I found the below link to be well explained with examples:
https://testdriven.io/blog/drf-views-part-3/

Comment: I'm trying to implement the explicit routes in my URLs.py, but I keep getting a type error. @trigo

Comment: TypeError: APIView.as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @CarterJames 
Did you try :
" You should separate out the classes eg: ListCreateAPIView, RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView ? "

Comment: @CarterJames check out my edit section in answer.