# Multiple same requests in django rest class based view

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I recently began using class-based views in the development of Django rest APIs.

While discussing this with a friend, he inquired, "What if I have the same type of request multiple times in the same class?"

because, as stated in the rest documentation, I created `post` functions for POST requests and `get` functions for GET requests.

So, how to write two GET or other types of requests within the same class?

Comment: *how to write two GET or other types of requests within the same class?* -  Django handles just a request at a time in development mode but in production you can use web servers like [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/), [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which can handle multiple requests & requests & I'll suggest read about [Client-Server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Client-Server_overview) structure

Comment: Possible repeat of the below stack-overflow question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300610/multiple-get-methods-in-same-class-in-django-views

Comment: @trigo is this how to write in rest api also?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What do you mean by "two GET or other type of requests"? If you mean two `get()` methods for different purposes, then they are different views and should be in different classes, clearly.  If you mean "handle multiple requests at the same time", then you would use a production server with multiple workers (gunicorn, etc).  If you mean something else entirely...

Comment: @Andrew that is not correct. Using Django Viewset and routers you can address two GET in same class.

Comment: What?  Are you talking about @actions?  This question is about views, anyway, not viewsets.  On the other hand, its just code I guess you can do anything you want :shrug:

Answer (score -1):

Was trying out the earlier accepted answer, does not seem to be correct.

The below solution is what shall work for you.

For multiple GET request in same api you need to implement Django Viewset and routers.

I found the below link to be well explained with examples:
https://testdriven.io/blog/drf-views-part-3/